# Post complex objects with Flask-marshmallow and flask-restful

Tags: python, json, rest, flask

I'm developing an API to learn Flask using flask-restful and flask-marshmallow and I would like to know if it's possible to post and serialize a list of complex objects at once.

Here's my current code:

```
class Post(db.Document):
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, required=True)
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    slug = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    body = db.StringField(required=True)
    comments = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Comment'))

    meta = {
        'allow_inheritance': True,
        'indexes': ['-created_at', 'slug'],
        'ordering': ['-created_at']
    }


class Comment(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, required=True)
    body = db.StringField(verbose_name="Comment", required=True)
    author = db.StringField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255, required=True)


class PostSerializer(Serializer):
    id = fields.String()
    class Meta:
        additional = ("created_at", "title", "slug", "body", "comments")


# just a test for multiple data
class PostViewList(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument('posts', type = str, action='append',
                                   required = True, help = 'No posts given',
                                   location='json')

    def post(self):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()

        serializer = PostSerializer(many=True)
        result = serializer.load(args['posts'])

        return args["posts"], 201

api.add_resource(PostViewList, '/posts')
```

The way it is right now, I receive an error on "serializer.load" because the post is not treated as an object, but as a string. If i dont try to serialize and return the "args['posts']" it show me the whole string I've posted.

I tried post the following Json:

```
{"posts":[ { "title":"asd", "slug": "asd", "body" : "asd" }, { "title":"qwe", "slug": "qwe", "body" : "qwe" }]}
```

The way it is right now, I haven't sent yet a list of comments, because I can't even process just the process that I didn't tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out after a while.

I've implemented the make_object on the PostSerializer, and declared a serializer for the comment too, nested as many with the post:

```
class CommentsSerializer(Serializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("created_at", "body", "author")

class PostSerializer(Serializer):
    id = fields.String()
    title = fields.String(required=True)
    comments = fields.Nested(CommentsSerializer, many=True)

    def make_object(self, data):
        return Post(**data)

    class Meta:
        additional = ("slug", "body", "created_at")
```

And then, on the post method, just got the json from flask, validated and serialized everything

```
class PostViewList(Resource):
    def post(self):
        if not request.get_json():
            return bad_request('No input data provided')    
        content_input = request.get_json().get("posts")    
        serializer = PostSerializer(many=True)
        errors = serializer.validate(content_input)
        if errors:
            return jsonify(errors), 400    
        result = serializer.load(content_input)    
        r = Post.objects.insert(result.data)
        return PostSerializer(r, many=True).data, 201
```

Comment: Can I ask why you use `validate` and then `load` when `load` only already returns the validation errors ? You can do `data, errors = serializer.load(content_input)` and then `if errors: abort(400, **errors)`

Comment: I didn`t know at the time, I was just fooling around with Flask for the first time, but thanks for the improvement